# Why am I getting a KeyError after reading values from .txt file?

Tags: python, vertex, keyerror, degrees

So I'm trying to change an already-working program to read from a .txt file, but I only see a KeyError.

```
#V = ([1,2,3,4,5])
#E = ([(1,2),(1,3),(2,3),(3,5),(5,4)])

import ast
with open('v.txt') as V:
  A = ast.literal_eval(V.read())
with open('e.txt') as E:
  B = ast.literal_eval(E.read())

print(A)
print(B)

indegree = {}
outdegree = {}

for x in A:
  indegree[x] = 0
  outdegree[x] = 0

for x,y in B:
  outdegree[x] += 1
  indegree[y] += 1

for x in A:
  print("Outdegree for vertex", x,"=", outdegree[x])
  print("Indegree for vertex", x,"=", indegree[x])
```

The output is:

> [(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)]
>
> [(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (3, 5), (5, 4)]
>
> line 21, in 
>   outdegree[x] += 1
>
> KeyError: 1

When I run it with values from `#V` and `#E` and the beginning of the code, it runs completely fine.

Comment: I dont see any issue with your code.

Comment: Print out `indegree` or `outdegree` after the loop over `A`, and you will see that they contain something like `{(1, 2, 3, 4, 5): 0}` - a single entry, with everything in one tuple.  You need to either remove one layer of nesting in v.txt, or loop over `A[0]` instead of `A`.

Comment: @jasonharper removing nesting helped, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the commented 'V' above has the shape

```
([1,2,3,4,5])
```

This gets read in and interpreted to the inner list, when I run it on my console, becoming:

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

However, notice in your print statements that instead, A is written as a list of a single tuple. The nesting is different.

```
[(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)]
```

When you iterate over the first dimension of A, you'll only instantiate the hashmap as follows:

```
{(1, 2, 3, 4, 5): 0}
```

My guess is the intended behavior is `{1: 0, 2:0, ...}`. I'd suggest that you use standard data formats (like tsv/csv) to simplify loading the data. Second, if you switch the order of brackets, you should get your intended answer